# C deleting the first and last element

Tags: c

I have an array (in a C-based-language), `char eItem[32]`.

For each "i" these values are loaded:

```
{ WADMIN, WADMIN, WADMIN, WADMIN, PALA, PALA, PALA, PALA }
```

Now, I wrote this code to delete first and last element from each value.

```
for ( i = 0; i <= 7; i++ ) {
    // code to get values
    k = strlen( eItem );
    eItem[k - 1] = "";
    eitem[0] = "";
    printf( eItem );
}
```

Very simple, yet it doesn't work. How come?

Comment: You do know you're assigning a string to a char, right?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: Maybe you want char* instead of char?

Comment: What are WADMIN, PALA? How are they defined?

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a string to a single element of a string (a character).  Instead, you need to assign a character, using single quotes.  For instance, to put a space in front and at the end of the word, which is what you seem to be trying to do:

```
eItem[k-1]=' ';
eItem[0]=' ';
```

But you can actually truncate the string at the beginning by making a separate character pointer point to the second character in the string, and truncate at the end by adding a NULL byte:

```
eItem[k-1]='\0';
char * truncated_eItem = eItem + 1;
```

Remember, the `+1` means it points to an address `1 *  sizeof(char)` downstream in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
eItem = eItem+1;
eItem[strlen(eItem)-1] = 0;
```

Comment: Not going to work inside a loop, since you're making your string shorter on each iteration.  You'd want to use a separate character pointer: `char * truncated_eItem = eItem + 1`.  Or you can just `printf( eItem + 1 )`.

Comment: You should write a sentence or two to explain why this should work, rather than dumping code as an answer.

Comment: @1" Somehow I was supposing that eItem is of type char* []... PerricOxide already asked this the author. Will see the answer.

Comment: @Sam. Sorry, got excited assuming that the right answer is self-explaining. Now I see it well may be not a right answer. :-) Next time will try to clarify question first.

Answer (score 0):

Marian,

Please go through the following implementation of the purpose. It should reasonably work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  const char *src_strings[]={"WADMIN", "WADMIN", "WADMIN", "WADMIN", "PALA", "PALA", "PALA", "PALA"}; //source array of char pointers
  char *dest_strings[8]; //Destination array of character pointers
  int string_count,length,cindex;

  printf("Modified Strings\n");
  printf("================\n");

  //Traverse through the strings in the source array
  for(string_count=0;string_count<8; string_count++) 
  {
    //Compute the lenght and dynamically allocate the
    //required bytes for the destination array
    length=strlen(src_strings[string_count]);
    dest_strings[string_count]= (char*)malloc(sizeof(length-1));

    //Copy characters to destination array except first and last
    for(cindex=1; cindex<length-1; cindex++)
    {
       *(dest_strings[string_count]+cindex-1)=*(src_strings[string_count]+cindex);
    }

    //Append null character
    *(dest_strings[string_count]+cindex)='\0';
    printf("%s\n",dest_strings[string_count]);

    //Free memory as it is not needed
    free(dest_strings[string_count]);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

#### Sample Output

```
Modified Strings
================
ADMI
ADMI
ADMI
ADMI
AL
AL
AL
AL
```